# Puppet Dashboard permissions: Permission denied - /var/lib/puppet/reports/

Tags: puppet

I'm setting up the Puppet Dashboard for the first time.  I have it running with the passenger module in Apache.

`sudo rake RAILS_ENV=production reports:import`

When I run this command, the tasks appear in the dashboard as failed.

> 630 new failed tasks

The details for each failure look something like this:

```
Importing report 201212270754.yaml at 2012-12-27 09:21 UTC
Permission denied - /var/lib/puppet/reports/rb-db1/201212270754.yaml
Backtrace
/usr/share/puppet-dashboard/app/models/report.rb:86:in `read'
/usr/share/puppet-dashboard/app/models/report.rb:86:in `create_from_yaml_file'
```

The report files were owned by puppet:puppet with a 640 permission by default.

I ran chmod a+rw on the reports directory, but I still get the same errors.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the puppet-dashboard server as root instead of as the puppet-dashboard user, you will see this error. My system is using /usr/share/puppet-dashboard/script/server on centos 6.4 using the puppet-dashboard-1.2.23-1.el6.noarch rpm from puppetlabs.

Answer (score 0):

```
[root@hadoop01 puppet-dashboard]# cat /etc/sysconfig/puppet-dashboard
#
# path to where you installed puppet dashboard
#
DASHBOARD_HOME=/usr/share/puppet-dashboard
#DASHBOARD_USER=puppet-dashboard
DASHBOARD_USER=root
DASHBOARD_RUBY=/usr/bin/ruby
DASHBOARD_ENVIRONMENT=production
DASHBOARD_IFACE=0.0.0.0
DASHBOARD_PORT=3000
```

edit the file like above and then  run the command

```
/etc/init.d/puppet-dashboard restart  && /etc/init.d/puppet-dashboard-workers restart
```

my puppet-dashboard version is 1.2.23